# how to use escape characters in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to use some escape characters in my React application but I have not found any resource that how can I use escape character in my application.

Is any methodology available?

Comment: Please read the help section on how to ask questions. It is usual to include what you've tried.

Comment: @DarrenSweeny Its quite clear what he wants, I arrived here wanting to find out the same thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the **[same](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) escape as Javascript (ECMAScript)**

' single quote

" double quote

\ backslash

\n new line

\r carriage return

\t tab

\b backspace

\f form feed

**For the HTML portion, use HTML escape characters.**

There are some minor [gotchas](https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html),to be aware of like evaluating escape chars between { }

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with MyComponent. -->
</div>
```

**JSX:**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.info('Test line\nbreak');
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name} &lt;> </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent name="Stackoverflow  &lt; !-- comment in name -->" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**This program prints this to the console:**

```
Test line
break
```

**And the user's screen is the following:**

> Hello Stackoverflow < !-- comment in name --> <>